# WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=...' failed: Invalid frame header

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

Sockets work fine on localhost, but I keep facing this issue when trying to move the code to production.

My nginx config file:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

    location /peerjs {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    listen 443 ssl;


    ssl_certificate ...; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key ...; # managed by Certbot
}
```

My server-side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server(server, {
    allowEIO3: true,
    cors: {
        origin: "*"
    }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Client-side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
const socket = io();
</script>
```

I tried:

- Changing io() to http/https, domain, wss, etc
- Reconfiguring nginx in million different ways
- Reconfiguring cors etc

Notes:

- https://example.com/socket.io/... is accessible
- `curl "https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling"` returns:

*0{"sid":"...","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}*

- `curl "https://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket"` returns:

*{"code":3,"message":"Bad request"}*

Nothing seems to work.